# How can I take some messages from a Telegram channel, change something and forward it?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I want take some messages from a Telegram channel (not mine), change something (not filter but for example modify some words) and forward the message changed to other channels (mine or not).
I would like to see some structured code to start (NodeJS preferably)

I tried to download TForwarder, but it s able only to filter message, not changing.

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: I'm looking for a pseudo-code to start because i'm newbie to use Telegram api bot

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you just need a way to forward as copy, and not a bot! If that's the case, then just use Telegram X for Android

Comment: I need to change the message copied

Comment: @Antonio Well you can forward them as copy to Saved Message, edit them there, and forward them again

Comment: It has to be automatic, that's why i'm looking for a way to write a bot using Telegram API...I want select a channel and any times a type of message is sent there, I want take that message, edit it and forward it to my channel.